# VBA script ignores some cells

Tags: vba, excel

I've cobbled together the following script to sort each column so that empty cells/cells with errors in them are at the bottom. The problem is that it does not properly sort if there is only a single empty cell at the top of the column of data (Rows 4-1000) (leaves the empty cell there, but otherwise sorts correctly).

```
Sub toTop()
'
' toTop Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+t
'
Dim sheetName As String
Dim column As Integer

sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
column = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(3, column))
    Range(Cells(4, column), Cells(1000, column)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range(Cells(4, column), Cells(4, column)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(4, column), Cells(1000, column))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    column = column + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help,

Scott

EDIT: [Google Sheet Mock-up of Problem](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zaZBHPpbIaAa_Mb3EM4hjsRFhaDvMWzne9DrDLwc1k4/edit?usp=sharing). This is post sorting, note that E4 is still empty.

Comment: Kindly provide data that demonstrates the problem when used with your macro.  Edit your original post to either show the data, or a link to the data.

Comment: Your code starts at row 4, it does not start at the top of the column. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Davesexcel Sorry, I said the top of the column, but I did mean that it should start at row 4, Rows 1-3 are headers/drop-down lists used for adjusting the output.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry about that, I've updated the OP with a link to a mock-up. I am not able to share the actual data at this time. The mock-up should show what the problem is in cell E4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my low rep, I have to answer and not comment. Please try changing this line of in your VBA:
    .Header = xlGuess
to this:
    .Header = xlNo

Excel tends to make mistakes when order to decide when to determine whether to use your first row as headers or not. The supplied code will force Excel to not use the first row as a header, but rather as sortable data.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for the suggestion @Bad_neighbor I'd up your cred, but mine's so low that I can't affect yours.